# This old fashion drinking fountain leaks. How do I fix it?

Tags: repair, plumbing-fixture

This old fashion drinking fountain leaks just a little bit from the spout, sometimes but not always. The on-off handle does not always spring back to the fully off position.  So a little water dribbles out of the spout.  How might I go about fixing this so it turns off fully?  Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a Halsey Taylor ["bracket style" fountain](http://www.halseytaylor.com/4540+ftn)

You could contact them for repair parts availability, or call plumbing supply houses now that you have a manufacturer and model.

If you open the [installation instructions](http://www.halseytaylor.com/wcsstore/lkdocs/care-cleaning-install-warranty-sheets/97003c.pdf), it provides a parts list that includes

> 600116618640 Stem Assy W/Lever

I googled that part number, and found this image at [amazon](http://amzn.com/B00VC706HW):
[image: valve stem assembly]

And that looks like there is a gasket at the threaded collar that goes into the body of the housing, and a simple flat washer at the end of the stem. I'd replace the flat washer, and clean it out well first.

Comment: What part(s) should I think of replacing? How do I know which part(s) to order?

Comment: @Yehuda: You might start by just adding some lubrication around the handle. If that didn't help I would isolate the water supply then dismantle the thing and look for worn, corroded, encrusted parts or parts that need lubrication.

Comment: Thanks @Tim B, I would have not had a clue on that one +. I think I would want to use a food grade lube but I don't know the breakdown of this style valve.